# How can I load a html link, inside of a html file

Tags: html

Is it possible to load the link https://clockmantellstime.github.io/Games/EZ%20money%201/ , inside of a file index.html? if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) to load external links to your website
like:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.ASP"></iframe>
```

Note that sites like YouTube wont load inside `<iframe>` as it is restricted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `load()` method i.e. in jQuery inside  with the extrenal